# Karaf bundle Jndi is not working as required

Tags: java, jetty, datasource, jndi, apache-karaf

I have created application using apache karaf and I need to connect Datasource using jndi but it is not working giving below error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env is not bound; remaining name 'env/jdbc/classicmodels'
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.getContext(NamingContext.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:101)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:157)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:157)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
```

And for this in Activator I am writing below code to configure jndi:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(ControllerConfig.class)
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

   // Bundle start stop code.
}
```

Now ControllerConfig code is as below:

```
@Configuration
@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
public class ControllerConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
    JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();

    factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> {
        org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
        classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
        classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");


        BasicDataSource simpleDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        simpleDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        simpleDataSource.setUsername("root");
        simpleDataSource.setPassword("root");
        simpleDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels");

        String jndiName = "jdbc/classicmodels";
        try {
            Resource resource = new Resource(server, jndiName, simpleDataSource);
            ///server.setAttribute("java:comp/env/" + jndiName, resource);
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    return factory;
}
}
```

If someone can help please let me know how to do it or what I am doing.

May it help someone just below changes are required and it will work:

```
 try {
            Context icontext = new InitialContext();
            Context compCtx = (Context) icontext.lookup("java:comp");
            compCtx.createSubcontext("env");
            new Resource("java:comp/env/" + jndiName, simpleDataSource);
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Is your stacktrace abbreviated in any way?  The entire stracktrace is useful in troubleshooting this, as it reveals critical scope layers.

Comment: You have registered your datasource with the name called `jdbc/classicmodels` but you've tried a lookup via the name `env/jdbc/classicmodels`. So I don't know if this deviation matters or the prefix `env` is implicit.